# Ionic with angular-google-maps directive

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have been trying to get angular-google-maps up and running and for the life of me i cannot firgure out why it is not working...

first i install the

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

here is the index html

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- google maps javascript -->
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
<script src="lib/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>

</head>
```

my map.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Map">
  <ion-content ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and finally my module and controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic','uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

myApp.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };

});
```

when this is run a get a blank screen on both chrome browser and on android phone.. any ideas what i may be doing wrong?? thanks for looking

so after moving google dependencies below ionic.bundle the map now loads... however i cannot set height to 100% using

```
.angular-google-map-container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

any ideas??

Comment: ok it turns out that i had to load google maps after ionic so i just inserted the scripts below ionic.bundle and it works still no idea how to get height set to 100% rather than pixel values.... and how to add driving directions... so...

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <map center="{{latitud}}, {{longitud}}" zoom="12" id="map_views" data-tap-disabled="true"></map>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
```

shall be loaded AFTER `ionic` as ionic bundle includes angular Framework

Comment: Does people how put a downvote knows why they do that ? 
My answer is 100% accurate concerning ANGULARJS & loading an angular Lib.